# dockerfile for chrome version 86.0.4240 from ubuntu

Tags: docker, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I have created pr baked docker image chrome version 86 from Ubuntu.
Following dockerfile i have used to create but failing to run container immediately?

```
#Step 1:
#chrome Browser
FROM ubuntu

#Step 2
#Essential tools and xvfb
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
software-properties-common \
unzip \
curl \
wget \
xvfb

#Step 3
#Chrome browser to run the tests
ARG CHROME_VERSION=86.0.4240
RUN curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add \
  && wget https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/downloadchrome.php?file=lnx%2Fchrome64_$CHROME_VERSION.deb \
  && dpkg -i download-chrome*.deb || true
RUN apt-get install -y -f \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#Disable the SUID sandbox so that chrome can launch without being in a privileged container
RUN dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome \
    && echo "#! /bin/bash\nexec /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox \"\$@\"" > /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome \
    && chmod 755 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

#Chrome Driver
ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=2.37
RUN mkdir -p /opt/selenium \
    && curl http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /opt/selenium/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && cd /opt/selenium; unzip /opt/selenium/chromedriver_linux64.zip; rm -rf chromedriver_linux64.zip; ln -fs /opt/selenium/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver;
```

Comment: how are you running the container? i cannot see any CMD or entrypoint in the dockerfile

Comment: yes, tried this also. Still the output is same

Comment: Not sure what you've tried or trying to achieve, please post the full dockerfile. If what you've posted is the full dockerfile, you've not specified what has to be executed when you run it. Please also provide the full command you're trying to execute?